# Adaptive Sampling Strategies for SVM?

Tags: svm, sampling

I am an Engineer interested in creating a surrogate model of a certain phenomenon in the context of reliability engineering. Essentially my quantity of interest is the Limit state function/stability boundary (The split between stable and unstable regions of a certain system) that can be extracted from the surrogate model.

I have used SVM (Regression) previously to create a surrogate model of a 'system' based on a Latin Hypercube Sampling plan to which I was able to extract the stability boundary, although this required many sample points (some even redundant) and thus a high computational cost.

Essentially, my previous work treated my SVM model as black box with no prescribed intelligence.

**My aim is to use an adaptive sampling strategy, with the aim of focusing *ONLY on the stability boundary* as opposed to creating an *accurate surrogate of the WHOLE system*, to increase the 'intelligence' of my SVM model. Are there any suggestions to any strategies in research/literature relevant to SVM?**
i.e. Contour location is of interest, contrast to a global surrogate.